# Finding the next date in an array of dates using + 1.day RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, date, methods

I have an appointment app. I am trying to build  "prev" and "next" links in an array of dates.  I am trying to find the "next" date by using the "current" date + 1.day...but this isn't working. The dates aren't always added sequentially, so I have to use the date and not the ID.  All the dates belong to a specific event...so they have to have that information.

EventDate Controller

```
def show
    @set_date  = AppointmentDate.find(params[:id])
    @event  = Event.find(@set_date.event_id)
    @next = @set_date.appointment_dates.where(schedule_date: @set_date.schedule_date + 1.day)
    @prev = @set_date.appointment_dates.where(schedule_date: @set_date.schedule_date - 1.day)

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the dates in array then use something like this:

```
@total = @records.length
current = @records.index(std_date(@date))
@next = @records[current + 1] if @records.length >= current + 1
@prev = @records[current - 1] if current != 0
@first = @records.first if current != 0
@last = @records.last if current + 1 < @records.length
@current = current + 1
```

where std_date is a helper function to convert date in dd/mm/yyyy and @date is today's date or whatever passed
@records is total number of records(dates) with dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: I had to remove std_date .... it was an "undefined function" and I don't need to display the date.  Thank you!